# Include auto generated primary key in Django ModelForm fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model where I didn't specify a primary key and Django generated one for me. Now I create a ModelForm for the model and I have specified `id` in the `fields` section of ModelForm. However, in my ModelForm object, the `id` field is not present.

Are only the model fields explicitly declared visible in the ModelForm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are only the model fields explicitly declared visible in the
>   ModelForm?

Yes, generally you don't want to mess with this field, if the user inputs a value for the id field it's very likely to be duplicated so this is something you want django to take care of for you.